# INSERT INTO WITH (TABLOCK) ocasionally not minimally logged

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, sql-server-2016, columnstore

I have an strange issue when loading a sql server 2016 (SP2 CU10) columnstore table. I'm using the query hint TABLOCK, so it should be minimally logged. On occasions (let's say 1 every 20 executions) the query will consume the full disk due to log growth of the transaction (100GB+). Only then to execute the exact same query with the exact same data a few minutes later, with log of basically nothing (10MB).

The query is as follows and on average loads around 100 million rows

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl1 WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT cols FROM tbl2
```

Checking query store, the plan is exactly the same between the "normal" execution and the "log growth" execution.
The only assumption I have is due to server conditions at that moment. If there is server pressure the query decides to log the full insert...but I cant find anything in relation to this.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to ask over at https://dba.stackexchange.com. There could be many factors. For instance if a periodic CHECKPOINT has not been issued then the dirty writes may not have been flushed from memory to disk. I doubt this is the cause but it can contribute to a lag in logging.

Comment: Can it be that on occasions you load LESS than 102400 rows?

Comment: Minimal logging for a bulk insert on a columnstore requires a batch size of 102400 or more, so data can go directly to a compressed row group. Since you're getting data by selecting it from another table, it's conceivable that somewhere in the execution plan the optimizer is generating batches of less than that (or expecting batches of less than that). It's hard to see how that would happen if the contents of `tbl2` remain the same between executions, though.